# Grafana query to retrive the count of requests using prometheus

Tags: java, grafana, prometheus

I have been using prometheus to monitor calls to my java api .
here is how i am monitoring my controller.

```
    static final Summary requestLatency = Summary.build().name("requests_latency")
                .help("Request latency in seconds.").register();
Summary.Timer requestTimer = requestLatency.startTimer();
        try {
// application logic
}
} finally {
            requestTimer.observeDuration();
        }
```

I am trying to write a query in grafana to get the current "requests_latency" per 5 minutes. 
what should be the query to get the "requests_latency" per 5 minutes. For example if i have 100 requests at 10:00 am and then no request came after that untill 11:00 am. So  the graph should show 100 at 10:00 am and 0 at 10:05 am and then 0 should continue till until more requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rate(requests_latency_sum[5m]) / rate(requests_latency_count[5m])`

Also, by convention the metric should be called `request_latency_seconds` so that the unit is clear.

Comment: i used the rate .but this is giving me two legends with same names in grafana. one is my actual latency value and other one is always zero (i have only one query).